# Glassfish4.1.1: useBundledJsf fails (partially): causes Target Unreachable, identifier ... resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-4, mojarra

Glassfish 4.1.1
NetBeans 8.1

javax.faces-2.2.8-12.jar OR javax.faces-2.2.8-17.jar OR javax.faces-2.3.0-m06.jar

---

Reported as: [JAVASERVERFACES-4182](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4182)

---

I am experienced with JSF, and am confident this problem is not one of the typical causes of the infamous:

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'viewBean' resolved to null
```

I am using a mini test web app to compare some JSF version as above, and rather than tediously copying various Mojarra implementation jars over the glassfish/modules I am using this in glassfish-web.xml:

```
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />
<class-loader delegate="false" />
```

And between runs I use the NetBeans library jar manager to choose a JSF Mojarra version to test from a ./lib subfolder. When I use an application-specific Mojarra it is not resolving this (and the web app works fine when I use the built-in Mojarra in Glassfish):

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {
```

(and BTW yes I know javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean etc. are now deprecated).

I know that useBundledJsf is basically working at least partially because I have this in an index.xhtml landing page (before navigating to a page that uses the view scoped bean), and it echos the application-specific Mojarra jar version fine:

```
#{facesContext.class.package.implementationTitle}: #{facesContext.class.package.implementationVersion}
```

**Q: Did Glassfish officially abandon support for 'useBundledJsf', and can somebody please shed some light on how to (now) use an application-specific Mojarra jar easily (so I can swap them in and out without impacting on other webapps) ?**

I did not find the explanation I seek searching on the Glassfish JIRA.

On the Payara GitHub issues I found this: 
[useBundledJSF flag makes ServletContainerInitializer get an empty class set and breaks Mojarra 2.2.11 and up #170](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/710), where it reports:

> We tried updating our Mojarra version in our application from 2.2.10
>   to 2.2.12. I was surprised that the application did not work anymore
>   after the update.
>
> Digging a little deeper into the code it seems that from Mojarra
>   version 2.2.11 (+) the Mojarra library does not handle the annotation
>   scanning by itself anymore but relies on the container to provide the
>   classes which contain annotations.
>   When the flag "useBundledJSF" in glassfish-web.xml is set to true, the set of 
>   classes is empty and this has the effect that no annotated bean can be found.

It seems I am experiencing something similar.

*Possibly related: [JAVASERVERFACES-3957 @FacesComponent is not detected when using JSF with Spring Boot](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3957)*